# Query execution taking too much time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to executing a very large select query into a `temp_table`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tblp 
AS (my select query which is very long, consists of many inner joins)
```

- This query is running for a long time (more than 6 mins because I just selected only a few amounts of criteria in the where clause and date period is taken for 10 Days in actual case this will be for one month)  and returns `4443 rows`

and [here](http://pastebin.com/0F4yRyXp) is my query

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: It is hard to give advice if you do not show the query that you are executing

Comment: @Arion sure i'll show the query

Comment: @Arion [here](http://pastebin.com/0F4yRyXp) is my query

Comment: Format the query to make it readable.

Comment: @StanislavL just see again I've edited

Comment: You call that "readable"?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari You can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24030423/edit) me

Comment: A few `IN`s would make that query so much better.

Comment: @JakubKania can you just give a brief explain ?

Comment: @hector Sure, this: `gtab04.PatentId = 321 OR gtab04.PatentId = 313 OR 
gtab04.PatentId = 267 OR gtab04.PatentId = 431` can be easily changed to: `gtab04.PatentId IN (267,313,321,431)`. It makes it more readable, shorter and makes it more error proof.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? By the way, the query is unreadable. Advice: Start rewriting your query, start all over again.

Comment: @FrankHeikens see [this](http://pastebin.com/kCr8HLsq)

Comment: This is your biggest problem: 
Index Scan using gtab10_tranid_idx on gtab10 gtab10_6 (cost=0.42..1.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=34001291). 34001291 times 0.005ms is long time... Rewrite your query and keep it as simple as possible. Also take a look at Common Table Expressions.

Comment: @FrankHeikens to be frank what are steps should i do ?? need to do anything in index ? - am new in programming

Comment: You have to start all over again to write a simple query, without all those subqueries. Maybe you could move some of these to a common table expression or another join, I don't know. I can't help you either, I have no idea what you're goal is.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SET temp_buffers = '1GB'; 
SET work_mem = '1GB';
set shared_buffers='1GB';
set effective_cache_size='1GB';
```

before executing  your `query`, the above values is for `3GB` RAM

- shared_buffers should be 10% to 25% of available RAM
- effective_cache_size should be 75% of available RAM

Comment: Queryplan doesn't show real issues with the configuration. A descend configuration is always a good idea, but not a silver bullet for all your performance issues.